# SharePoint 2013 - Users from domain 2 keep getting login prompt cannot access content

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We have SharePoint 2013 on premise in domain 1 and we have a new domain, say domain 2. I was able to configure the People picker in SharePoint so it can see users in domain 2 but when doamin 2 users attempt to login to access content they get the following:

[image]

There is a full 2 way trust between the domains and we're using NTLM authentication. What should I be checking to determine why domain 2 users can't login to SharePoint? I'm trying to determine if this is a SharePoint issue versus an IIS issue.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could Disable the loop back check according to the following steps:

1. Click Start->search Run->type regedit->then click OK.
2. In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa

3. Right-click Lsa->click New-> click DWORD Value.
4. Type “DisableLoopbackCheck”, and then press ENTER.
5. Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
6. In the Value data box, type 1 and then click OK.
7. Quit Registry Editor.
8. Restart the computer.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[SharePoint disable loopback check (DisableLoopbackCheck dword in registry)](https://sharepointsolutiontips.blogspot.com/2016/07/disable-loop-back-check-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Thank you for your info but the reference link you provided is broken.

Comment: I have updated the reply.